# Horizontal line is not appearing at the end of table in two-column document

Tags: tables

I am trying to insert a table into a two column document with the following code but in the output there is no horizontal line after the last row.

```latex
\begin{table*}[t]
\centering
\caption{Classification of river sediment}
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
    Particle & Clay & Silt & Sand & Gravel & Cobbles & Boulders\\ \hline
    Size (mm) & $<0.002$ & $0.002-0.06$ & $0.06-2$ & $2-60$ & $60-250$ & $>250$ \hline
\end{tabular}
\label{tab:1}
\end{table*}
```

[image]

Comment: You are missing the row break before the second `\hline`.

Comment: you need `Size (mm) & $<0.002$ & $0.002-0.06$ & $0.06-2$ & $2-60$ & $60-250$ & $>250$ \\ \hline`

Comment: @SATYAM did the answer below meet your requirement

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

```
\begin{table*}[t]
    \centering
    \caption{Classification of river sediment}
    \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
        \hline
        Particle & Clay & Silt & Sand & Gravel & Cobbles & Boulders\\ \hline
        Size (mm) & $<0.002$ & $0.002-0.06$ & $0.06-2$ & $2-60$ & $60-250$ & $>250$ 
        \\\hline%<------------------------new
    \end{tabular}
    \label{tab:1}
\end{table*}
```